# How to select the top_k of one column, sorted by another column, within a third column in Polars?

Tags: python-polars

I was writing some code and realized this might be a reasonably common operation. I also realized I don't know a clean way to do it.

The questions is: Get the top 5 entries in column1, sorted by column2, within groups given by column3.

If I had to intuit how this would be writen in Polars it'd be:

```
df.select(pl.col('column1').top_k(n=5, by='column2').over('column3'))
```

But note that is made up code; it does not work.

Consider this sample data:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import polars as pl 


data_size = 10_000_000

np.random.seed = 1
saleValue    = np.random.randint(0, 100, data_size)
storeId      = np.random.choice([f'Store: {i}' for i in range(200_000)], replace=True, size=data_size)
customerId   = np.random.choice([f'Customer: {i}' for i in range(1_000)], replace=True, size=data_size)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(storeId=storeId, customerId=customerId, saleValue=saleValue)
).pipe(pl.from_pandas)
```

It generates a dataframe of the form:

```
┌───────────────┬───────────────┬───────────┐
│ storeId       ┆ customerId    ┆ saleValue │
│ ---           ┆ ---           ┆ ---       │
│ str           ┆ str           ┆ i32       │
╞═══════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════════╡
│ Store: 161472 ┆ Customer: 960 ┆ 29        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 168620 ┆ Customer: 814 ┆ 21        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 37904  ┆ Customer: 80  ┆ 61        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 166077 ┆ Customer: 516 ┆ 23        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 141748 ┆ Customer: 549 ┆ 58        │
└─///───────────┴─///───────────┴─///───────┘
```

I'm curious how one would get the top 5 customer per store, sorted by their total spend.

One solution is:

```
(df

  # This part is essential; we need to get the total spend (sales)
 .groupby(['storeId','customerId'])
 .agg(pl.col('saleValue').sum().alias('totalSales'))

  # This is the part I think could be cleaner
 .sort('totalSales', reverse=True)
 .groupby('storeId')
 .agg(pl.col('customerId').head(5).list().alias('customerIds'))
)

┌───────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ storeId       ┆ customerIds                         │
│ ---           ┆ ---                                 │
│ str           ┆ list[str]                           │
╞═══════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Store: 78152  ┆ ["Customer: 753", "Customer: 170... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 67676  ┆ ["Customer: 957", "Customer: 896... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 45152  ┆ ["Customer: 118", "Customer: 127... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 183339 ┆ ["Customer: 370", "Customer: 227... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 144688 ┆ ["Customer: 328", "Customer: 294... │
└─///───────────┴─///─────────────────────────────────┘
```

But I wonder if there is something cleaner using `.top_k`

Comment: I think you might want to look [here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/window/#window-expression-rules:~:text=More-,examples,-For%20more%20exercise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done a bit cleaner indeed, although you are close.

Define the first step as `df_agg` (for the sake of this answer, you can chain):

```py
df_agg = df.groupby(['storeId','customerId']).agg(pl.col('saleValue').sum().alias('totalSales'))
```

Then we can do:

```py
df_agg.groupby('storeId').agg(pl.col('customerId').sort_by('totalSales', reverse=True).slice(0,5))
```

Which reads as:

- group by store
- take column customer id
- we sort the values of this column by the column totalSales, from high to low (reverse=True)
- we take the first 5 values of customer id

So we do the groupby like you proposed, but the sorting is done inside the aggregation using `sort_by`, rather than on the full dataframe. Also, I use `slice` rather than `head` + `list`.

On your point on `top_k`: this function returns the largest elements of itself, not by another. Polars has sufficient ways of achieving what you want, notably `sort_by`, that I dont think there is a need to complicate the implementation of `top_k` by adding a `by` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Would using `top_k` in a filter work for you?  For example:

```py
(
    df.groupby(["storeId", "customerId"])
    .agg(pl.col("saleValue").sum().alias("totalSales"))
    .filter(
        pl.col("totalSales")
        >= pl.col("totalSales").top_k(k=5).list().over("storeId").arr.last()
    )
)
```

```
shape: (1048652, 3)
┌───────────────┬───────────────┬────────────┐
│ storeId       ┆ customerId    ┆ totalSales │
│ ---           ┆ ---           ┆ ---        │
│ str           ┆ str           ┆ i64        │
╞═══════════════╪═══════════════╪════════════╡
│ Store: 92626  ┆ Customer: 829 ┆ 98         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 56532  ┆ Customer: 840 ┆ 93         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 159073 ┆ Customer: 684 ┆ 88         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 131292 ┆ Customer: 836 ┆ 98         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 73245  ┆ Customer: 545 ┆ 93         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 31163  ┆ Customer: 554 ┆ 91         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 128047 ┆ Customer: 971 ┆ 89         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 41563  ┆ Customer: 85  ┆ 92         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 157951 ┆ Customer: 45  ┆ 97         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 7677   ┆ Customer: 390 ┆ 88         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...           ┆ ...           ┆ ...        │
```

Adding a sort to make the result easier to inspect:

```py
(
    df.groupby(["storeId", "customerId"])
    .agg(pl.col("saleValue").sum().alias("totalSales"))
    .filter(
        pl.col("totalSales")
        >= pl.col("totalSales").top_k(k=5).list().over("storeId").arr.last()
    )
    .sort(["storeId", "totalSales"], reverse=[False, True])
)
```

```
shape: (1048652, 3)
┌──────────────┬───────────────┬────────────┐
│ storeId      ┆ customerId    ┆ totalSales │
│ ---          ┆ ---           ┆ ---        │
│ str          ┆ str           ┆ i64        │
╞══════════════╪═══════════════╪════════════╡
│ Store: 0     ┆ Customer: 46  ┆ 151        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 0     ┆ Customer: 267 ┆ 102        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 0     ┆ Customer: 354 ┆ 94         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 0     ┆ Customer: 416 ┆ 93         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 0     ┆ Customer: 729 ┆ 93         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 1     ┆ Customer: 459 ┆ 99         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 1     ┆ Customer: 417 ┆ 90         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 1     ┆ Customer: 982 ┆ 89         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 1     ┆ Customer: 337 ┆ 86         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 1     ┆ Customer: 202 ┆ 84         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...          ┆ ...           ┆ ...        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 99998 ┆ Customer: 536 ┆ 99         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 99998 ┆ Customer: 295 ┆ 99         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 99998 ┆ Customer: 841 ┆ 98         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 99998 ┆ Customer: 782 ┆ 94         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 99999 ┆ Customer: 29  ┆ 96         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 99999 ┆ Customer: 84  ┆ 96         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 99999 ┆ Customer: 557 ┆ 96         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 99999 ┆ Customer: 885 ┆ 91         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 99999 ┆ Customer: 866 ┆ 89         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Store: 99999 ┆ Customer: 695 ┆ 89         │
└──────────────┴───────────────┴────────────┘
```

From the above, you can proceed to create a list for each store (or whatever you need).

Note: this approach may produce more than 5 customers per store.  (It does not break ties, as shown for Store 99999 at the bottom).